# How to decrypt data before the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I decrypt a field before it is shown in the view? Right now I'm calling the method to encrypt that field, then save that encryption inside the database, then after I want to decrypt that value so it is shown properly inside the view. Both encrypt and decrypt method work, the problem as stated is that I don't know where to call the decrypt function before the view loads.

I want that the decryption is done as this view is being shown

```
public ActionResult Item()
{
   Repository rep = new Repository();
   var getItems = rep.GetItems();
   return View(getItems);
}
```

Comment: You should decrypt before you pass it to the view (the line `return View(getItems);` (not in your repository class, create a service which will handle the encryption/decryption tasks)

Comment: @C1sc0 yes I've done that but the thing is that the view gets the encrypted data, hence I need to decrypt than show the decrypted result without saving it

Comment: Create a service called Crypt, pass the whole Repository to it's constructor (new Crypt(rep);), and create a method in the crypt class, name it (GetDecryptedItems), and query the items in it, decrypt the necessary fileds, and return them (var getItems = crypt.GetDecryptedItems();) and at this point all fields are  in decrypted form, you shouldn't decrypt the fileds in the view...

Comment: @C1sc0 Thanks, but I only need to decrypt one field

Comment: Can you show us your model and clarify which field is encrypted please... can you also show us your decrypt method.

Answer (score 1):

When you have service layer, should decrypt in service layer in other way to decrypt in Item action or in Item.cshtml (View file)

Comment: Didn't really understand what you said. Should I call the decryption in the Item.cshtml?

Comment: in code block which begin with @. For examle @{  to decrypt method here }

Comment: @{decription(item.Name)} I've done it like this but it's giving me an error, should I include something else in the View ?

Comment: Like that it's giving me an error saying that the method doesn't exist in that context, do I need to add some header?

Comment: yes, add @using to Item.cshtml or _ViewImports.cshtml

Comment: Believe or not still I can't do this method haha. I'm adding @Html.Action("Decryption", "Item"); in the top of the view and @{decription(item.Name)} with the value but still can't figure out what's wrong

Comment: Maybe I am getting you wrong, but why don't you simply loop over your result before you return the view?